# nx react module federation hot reload

Tags: reactjs, webpack, nrwl-nx, nrwl, webpack-module-federation

I'm using module federation with nx and want to enable HMR.
I applied the `hmr: true` option in both `project.json` files. (for the host and the remote).
The problem that its working only for the remote, and when changing the code in the host project its not working and not updating it in the browser.

this is the configuration for the host `project.json` (I'm using `nx server`):

```
"serve": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/react:module-federation-dev-server",
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "client:build",
    "hmr": true,
    "port": 4200
  },
  "configurations": {
    "development": {
      "buildTarget": "client:build:development",
      "open": true,
      "watch": true,
      "liveReload": true
    },
    "production": {
      "buildTarget": "client:build:production",
      "hmr": false
    }
  }
}
```

and this is in the remote `project.json`

```
"serve": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/react:module-federation-dev-server",
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "assets:build",
    "hmr": true,
    "port": 4201
  },
  "configurations": {
    "development": {
      "buildTarget": "assets:build:development"
    },
    "production": {
      "buildTarget": "assets:build:production",
      "hmr": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've done it with @nrwl/web:dev-server and it is working (for vue3).
Why do you have liveReload and hmr in the same project.json activated ?

Comment: @PaulDreyer because `liveReload` is the only thing working for me. and I'm using react so it might be related

Answer (score 2):

It's not working with HMR. Well never got to make it work. But using live reload witht following config its working fine. I can even debug TS with source maps.

```js
module.exports = merge(custom, common, {
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dev'),
    publicPath: 'auto',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'dev'),
    hot: false,
    liveReload: true,
    port: infinisoft.moduleFederation.devport
  },
  plugins: [
    new MFLiveReloadPlugin({
      port: infinisoft.moduleFederation.devport,
      container: name,
      standalone: true
    }),
    new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
    new MinChunkSizePlugin({
      minChunkSize: 10000, // Minimum number of characters
    }),
    moduleFederation,
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'config', 'index.html'),
    }),
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
});
```

Comment: and is it possible to use it with the `withModuleFederation` method? from the `@nrwl/react/module-federation` package?

Comment: I have never tried.